# ../this returns the view object inside inner loop when the parent and child have the same value

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, view-helpers

I am just starting with `handlebars` and I am trying to do a simple double for loop in order to have all the day's time with 15 minute intervals. A very weird thing is happening where if the child and parent have the same values, the `view` object is being returned instead. This is my code:

```
var handlebarsExpress = require('express-handlebars').create({
    helpers: {
        for: function(from, to, incr, block) {
            var accum = '';
            for(var i = from; i <= to; i += incr) {
                accum += block.fn(i);
            }
            return accum;
        }
    }
});

app.engine('handlebars', handlebarsExpress.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

...
...
```

In the view file (`sth.handlebars`) i have this:

```
<div class="row columns large-12">
    {{#for 0 23 1}}
        {{#for 0 45 15}}
            {{log ../this}}
            <span>{{../this}}:{{this}}</span><br>
        {{/for}}
    {{/for}}
</div>
```

The html output is something like this:

```
[object Object]:0
0:15
0:30
0:45
1:0
...
...
13:45
14:0
14:15
14:30
14:45
15:0
[object Object]:15
15:30
15:45
16:0
16:15
```

The `log` helper reports the following in the terminal:

```
{ settings: 
   { 'x-powered-by': true,
     etag: 'weak',
     'etag fn': [Function: wetag],
     env: 'development',
     'query parser': 'extended',
     'query parser fn': [Function: parseExtendedQueryString],
     'subdomain offset': 2,
     'trust proxy': false,
     'trust proxy fn': [Function: trustNone],
     view: [Function: View],
     views: '/home/elsa/Projects/rental-borg/project/views',
     'jsonp callback name': 'callback',
     'view engine': 'handlebars',
     port: 8765 },
  flash: { info: undefined, error: undefined },
  _locals: { flash: { info: undefined, error: undefined } },
  cache: false }
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
4
...
...
13
13
13
13
14
14
14
14
15
{ settings: 
   { 'x-powered-by': true,
     etag: 'weak',
     'etag fn': [Function: wetag],
     env: 'development',
     'query parser': 'extended',
     'query parser fn': [Function: parseExtendedQueryString],
     'subdomain offset': 2,
     'trust proxy': false,
     'trust proxy fn': [Function: trustNone],
     view: [Function: View],
     views: '/home/elsa/Projects/rental-borg/project/views',
     'jsonp callback name': 'callback',
     'view engine': 'handlebars',
     port: 8765 },
  flash: { info: undefined, error: undefined },
  _locals: { flash: { info: undefined, error: undefined } },
  cache: false }
15
15
16
16
16
16
...
23
23
23
23
```

It is apparent that when `this` and `../this` are equal, `../this` actually returns something like `../../this` which is the view object itself, I suppose. This happens twice in my specific case, on 00:00 and on 15:15.

Is this a bug?

EDIT: I solved the problem with the new Block Parameters feature of Handlebars 3, but the initial question remains. This is what I did to solve the problem:

`.handlebars` file:

```
{{#for 0 23 1 as |hour|}}
    {{#for 0 45 15 as |minute|}}
        <span>{{hour}}:{{minute}}</span>
    {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

and the helper:

```
for: function(from, to, incr, block) {
    var args = [], options = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }

    var accum = '';
    for(var i = from; i <= to; i += incr) {
        accum += options.fn(i, {data: options.data, blockParams: [i]});
    }
    return accum;
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an intriguing discovery and I really wanted to find the reason for such seemingly strange behavior. I did some digging into the [Handlebars source code](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js) and I found the relevant code was to be found on [line 176 of lib/handlebars/runtime.js](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/runtime.js#L176).

Handlebars maintains a stack of context objects, the top object of which is the `{{this}}` reference within the currently executing Handlebars template block. As nested blocks are encountered in the executing template a new object is pushed to the stack. This is what permits code like the following:

```
{{#each this.list}}
    {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

On the first line, `this` is an object with an enumerable property called "list". On line two, `this` is the currently iterated item of the `list` object. As the question points out, Handlebars allows us to use `../` to access context objects deeper in the stack. In the example above, if we want to access the `list` object from within the `#each` helper, we would have had to use `{{../this.list}}`.

With this brief summary out of the way, the question remains: Why does our context stack appear to break when the value of the current iteration of the outer `for` loop is equal to that of the inner `for` loop?

The [relevant code](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/runtime.js#L176) from the Handlebars source is the following:

```
let currentDepths = depths;
if (depths && context != depths[0]) {
  currentDepths = [context].concat(depths);
}
```

`depths` is the internal stack of context objects, `context` is the object passed to the currently executing block, and `currentDepths` is the context stack that is made available to the executing block. As you can see, the current `context` is pushed to the available stack *only if* `context` is not [loosely equal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) to the current top of the stack, `depths[0]`.

Let's apply this logic to the code in the question.

When the context of the outer `#for` block is `15` and the context of the inner `#for` block is `0`:

- `depths` is: `[15, {ROOT_OBJECT}]` (Where {ROOT_OBJECT} means the
  object that was the argument to the template method call.)
- Becuase `0 != 15`,    `currentDepths` becomes: `[0, 15, {ROOT_OBJECT}]`.
- Within the inner `#for` block of the template, `{{this}}`
  is `0`, `{{../this}}` is `15` and `{{../../this}}` is {ROOT_OBJECT}.

However, when the outer *and* inner `#for` blocks each have a context value of `15`, we get the following:

- `depths` is: `[15, {ROOT_OBJECT}]`.
- Because `15 == 15`, `currentDepths = depths = [15, {ROOT_OBJECT}]`.
- Within the inner `#for` block of the template, `{{this}}` is `15`, `{{../this}}` is {ROOT_OBJECT}, and `{{../../this}}` is `undefined`.

This is why it appears that your `{{../this}}` skips a level when the outer and inner `#for` blocks have the same value. It is actually because the value of the inner `#for` is *not pushed* to the context stack!

It is at this point that we should ask why Handlebars behaves this way and to determine whether this is a feature or a bug.

It so happens that this code was added intentionally to solve an [issue](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1028) that users were experiencing with Handlebars. The issue can be demonstrated by way of example:

Assuming a context object of:

```
{
    config: {
        showName: true
    },
    name: 'John Doe'
}
```

Users found the following use case to be counter-intuitive:

```
{{#with config}}
    {{#if showName}}
        {{../../name}}
    {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

The specific issue was with the necessity for the double `../` to access the root object: `{{../../name}}` rather than `{{../name}}`. Users felt that since the context object within `{{#if showName}}` was the `config` object, then stepping-up one level, `../`, should access the "parent" of `config` - the root object. The reason that two steps were necessary was because Handlebars was creating a context stack object *for each* block helper. This means that two steps are required to get to the root context; the first step gets the context of `{{#with config}}`, and the second step gets the context of the root.

A [commit](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/commit/279e038ba7ff7e5966a60e36d326e2d4c310f0c6) was made that prevents the pushing of a context object to the available context stack when the new context object is *loosely equal* to the object at the top of the context stack. The responsible code is the source code we looked at above. As of [version 4.0.0](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/tree/v4.0.0) of Handlebars.js, our config example will fail. It now requires only a single `../` step.

Getting back to the code example in the original question, the reason that the `15` from the outer `#for` block is determined as equal to the `15` in the inner `#for` block is due to how number types are compared in JavaScript; two objects of the Number type are equal if they each have the same *value*. This is in contrast to the Object type, for which two objects are equal only if they *reference* the same object in memory. This means that if we re-wrote the original example code to use Object types instead of Number types for the contexts, then we would never meet the conditional comparison statement and we would *always* have the expected context stack within our inner `#for` block.

The for loop in our helper would be updated to pass an Object type as the context of the frame it creates:

```
for(var i = from; i <= to; i += incr) {
    accum += block.fn({ value: i });
}
```

And our template would now need to access the relevant property of this object:

```
{{log ../this.value}}
<span>{{../this.value}}:{{this.value}}</span><br>
```

With these edits, you should find your code performing as you expected.

It's somewhat subjective to declare whether or not this is a bug with Handlebars. The conditional was added intentionally and the resultant behavior does what it was intended to do. However, I find it hard to imagine a case in which this behavior would be expected or desirable when the contexts involved are primitives and *not* Object types. It might be reasonable for the Handlebars code to be made to do the comparison on Object types *only*. I think there is a legitimate case here to [open an issue](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues).

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks a lot, I was curious as well but didn't have the time to investigate