# Handlebars prints wrong thing when iterating through same array twice

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

Trying to print out all combinations of 2 items from an array.

```js
var source = document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {
  colors: ['red', 'blue', 'green']
};
var html = template(context);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.js"></script>
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
output:
  {{#colors}}
        {{#../colors}}
    color1: {{../this}} color2: {{this}};
        {{/../colors}}
    {{/colors}}
</script>
<pre id="output">
  </pre>
```

Here is a [**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/samkeddy/pen/GORXqR)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [../this returns the view object inside inner loop when the parent and child have the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935524/this-returns-the-view-object-inside-inner-loop-when-the-parent-and-child-have)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not yet sure what's causing it to behave that way, but you can fix it by using block parameters.

```js
var source = document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {
  colors: ['red', 'blue', 'green']
};
var html = template(context);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.js"></script>
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
output:
  {{#colors as |color1|}}
        {{#../colors as |color2|}}
    color1: {{color1}} color2: {{color2}};
        {{/../colors}}
    {{/colors}}
</script>
<pre id="output">
  </pre>
```

Comment: this solved this issue, but now I'm having a similar issue when adding a 3rd loop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041164/handlebars-prints-wrong-thing-when-iterating-through-same-array-thrice