# Handlebars nested loops with same array

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

`"handlebars": "^4.7.6"`

I have a problem with rendering neseted each for same array. Looks like it is some bug somewhere in the library.

Could you explain this:

js

```
testTemplate({'test': [
                    {'id':1,'row':0},
                    {'id':2,'row':0},
                    {'id':3,'row':1},
            ]})
```

handlebars

```
{{#each test}}
{{#each ../test}}
    <div class="row">{{this.id}} = {{../this.id}}</div>
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

result

```
    <div class="row">1 = </div>
    <div class="row">2 = 1</div>
    <div class="row">3 = 1</div>
    <div class="row">1 = 2</div>
    <div class="row">2 = </div>
    <div class="row">3 = 2</div>
    <div class="row">1 = 3</div>
    <div class="row">2 = 3</div>
    <div class="row">3 = </div>
```

for equal ids `{{../this.id}}` is gone. Why?

Comment: Are you sure you are doing what you need to do? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: Do you realize that you are trying to get the same values twice? https://jsfiddle.net/p8h4Lfmb/

Comment: I think this might be the same issue that I posted an explanation of here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955937/3397771

Comment: Man, of course I realize everything. This example not part of production code - it is a test. I think it is a bug and should be fixed. yr fiddle is not what I want. Good luck.

Comment: I debugged this. In equal case ../this = root object provided to template.{"test": [...]} This is bug.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve, I made an [example on JS](https://jsfiddle.net/p8h4Lfmb/)

if you want to get the same result, you can use the following hack:

```
{{#each test}}
    {{#each test}}
      {{#each ../test}}
          <div class="row">{{id}} = {{#if ../id}}{{../id}}{{/if}}{{#unless ../id}}{{id}}{{/unless}}</div>
    {{/each}}
 {{/each}}
```

Result:

```
1 = 1
2 = 1
3 = 1
1 = 2
2 = 2
3 = 2
1 = 3
2 = 3
3 = 3
```

This doesn't answer your question, but it might solve the problem